# Analog to utility classes in R?

Tags: r

I have a couple of functions that convert between coordinate systems, and they all rely on constants from the WGS84 ellipsoid, etc. I'd rather not have these constants pollute the global namespace. Similarly, not all of the functions need to be visible globally.

In Java, I'd encapsulate all the coordinate stuff in a utility class and only expose the coordinate transformation methods.

What's a low-overhead way to do this in R? Ideally, I could:

```
source("coordinateStuff.R")
```

at the top of my file and call the "public" functions as needed. It might make a nice package down the road, but that's not a concern right now.

---

Edit for initial approach:

I started coords.R with:

```
coords <- new.env()
with(coords, {
    ## Semi-major axis (center to equator)
    a <- 6378137.0
    ## And so on...
})
```

The `with` statement and indentation clearly indicate that something is different about the assignment variables. And it sure beats typing a zillion `assign` statements.

The first cut at functions looked like:

```
ecef2geodetic <- function (x,y,z) {
  attach(coords)
  on.exit(detach(coords))
```

The `on.exit()` ensures that we'll leave `coords` when the function exits. But the `attach()` statements caused trouble when one function in `coords` called another in `coords`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476881/determining-current-environment-or-maybe-im-going-about-this-all-wrong) to see how things went from there.

Answer (score 4):

Utility classes in Java are code smell. This is *not* what you want in R.

There are several ways of solving this in R. For medium / large scale things, the way to go is to put you stuff into a **package** and use it in the remaining code. That encapsulates your “private” variables nicely and exposes a well-defined interface.

For smaller things, an excellent way of doing this is to put your code into a **`local` call** which, as the name suggests, executes its argument in a local scope:

```
x <- 23
result <- local({
    foo <- 42
    bar <- x
    foo * bar
})
```

Finally, you can put your objects into a **list** or **environment** (there are differences but you may ignore them for now), and then just access them via `listname$objname`:

```
coordinateStuff <- list(
    foo = function () { cat('42\n') }
    bar = 23
)

coordinateStuff$foo()
```

If you want something similar to your `source` statement, [take a look at my `xsource` command](https://github.com/klmr/rcane/blob/master/xsource.R) which solves this to some extent (although it’s work in progress and has several issues!). This would allow you to write

```
cs <- xsource(coordinateStuff)

# Use cs as if it were an evironment, e.g.

cs$public_function()
# or even:
cs::public_function()
```

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue Yes, absolutely. Java made the design decision to have classes as the elementary code unit. And while this certainly simplifies certain things, it’s nonsense from a semantic perspective. Classes and code modules are separate concepts, mashing them together is neither required for OOP (although many Java users think that) nor does it serve a grander purpose.

Comment: Emulating java.lang.Math is what I had in mind. I fear that a few months spent programming in Java may have corrupted my brain. In any case, this gives me some good ideas to chew on.

Comment: And OOP is not required for effective and efficient programming. This "mixing" is a convenience for human programmers.  What grander purpose can there be?  @Andreas Yankopolus, I think R is a far bigger hodgepodge of stuff than Java is at this point. S3? S4? homegrown object ordainment?

Answer (score 1):

A package is the solution... But for a fast solution you could use Environments http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html

Comment: Thanks. This looks like an immediate solution that I can refine in the future.

Comment: Please **consider** building a package ;)