# Determining current environment, or maybe I'm going about this all wrong?

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use environments to keep specialized constants out of the global namespace and for potentially masking each other. This is resulting in a slew of warnings along the lines of `The following object(s) are masked from ...`.

I have:

```
foo <- new.env()
with(foo, {
    # Define variables pertaining to foo.
)}

bar <- new.env()
with(bar, {
    # Define variables pertaining to bar.
)}
```

Now it gets interesting. I have various functions that need to access the items in `foo` and `bar`. For example:

```
fooFunc1 <- function (args) {
    attach(foo)
    on.exit(detach(foo))

    ## Do foo things.
    fooFunc2()
}
```

Now, `fooFunc2` is defined similarly with an `attach()` statement at the top. This results in an warning that everything defined in `foo` has been masked. Which makes sense, because we're already in `foo`. The answer would appear to be having each function would check if it's already in the correct environment and only `attach()` if not. But I'm not seeing a way to name an environment to work with `environmentName()`.

So how do people actually effect encapsulation and hiding in R? Having to type `foo$fooVar1`, `foo$fooVar2`, etc. seems absurd. Same with wrapping every statement in `with()`. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not to use `with` again within fooFunc1 and fooFunc2?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some thing like:

```
if (!"foo" %in% search()) {attach(foo); on.exit(detach(foo))}
```

Or alternatively, use `local`:

```
fooFunc1 <- local(function(args) {
  ##Do foo things
  fooFunc2()
 }, env=foo)
```

Comment: regarding your first solution. what if OP had three nested functions, the first attaches foo, the second bar, and the third foo and say bar masks variables in foo. wouldn't this fail then, since foo is already in the search path? the third nested function would use the variables from bar instead, when it should be using them from foo?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `with` again. For example:

```
foo <- new.env()
with(foo,{x=1;y=2})
fooFunc1  <- function(){
    xx <- with(foo,{
        x^2+1/2
    })
}
```

Comment: The `with(foo, ...)` block appears to block access to arguments passed to `fooFunc1()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just turn off the conflict warnings with `attach(foo, warn.conflicts=FALSE)`. Alternatively, if you want to keep redundancies out of your searchpath, you could do something like this instead:

```
try(detach(foo), silent=TRUE)
attach(foo)
on.exit(try(detach(foo), silent=TRUE))
```

I think the best way, though, is to define the functions with the environment you want to run them in.

```
f <- function(...) {print(...)}
environment(f) <- foo
```

or equivalently,

```
f <- local({
    function(...) {print(...)}
}, env=foo)
```

Functions in R are all closures, meaning they're all bundled with a reference to the environment that they are supposed to run in. By default each function's environment is the environment in which it is created, but you can change this using the `environment` or `local` functions to any environment you want.

Comment: I'm liking the approach using `local()`, as it keeps everything nicely contained in one block, but it unfortunately kills ESS's ability to identify functions with `ess-function-pattern`.

Comment: sorry, can't speak to that. vim user here ;)